# Android screen record with development tools

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, intellij-13, screen-recording

Earlier this week, I was able to do a screen record via IntelliJ's scren record tool. The button is greyed out now. When running ddms.bat there, the feature is also greyed out.

Under what circumstances is this feature not available? How can I enable it again?

Comment: Are you using the android studio, right?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ. And i also tried using DDMs directly, a noted in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's dependent on the version of Android running on the device. It must be 4.4.4 or greater.

I had been testing on different android devices w\ different versions.